# Kubuntu screenshots not saving in images after i removed images folder and remade it

Tags: kubuntu

Kubuntu screenshots not saving in images after i removed images folder and remade it

I take screenshots with Meta+PrtScr and it by default saves in Images folder.

I moved all images to new drive and now new screenshots comes in Home folder. How to fix it to default Images folder?

Its still telling that saving in Pictures folder
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change the settings in the screenshot tool
Open spectacle and click Configure
[image]